# overflow hidden not working in ios devices using particles

Tags: javascript, ios, css, overflow, particles

I have a very simple landing page with some animated particles in the background which are small images.  Seems to work fine in typical browsers however when on any mobile ios platform (iphone/ipad etc) the particles seem to cause the view to constantly resize as they float to the boundaries of the page...  I thought overflow hidden would prevent this...
I'm at a loss on this one...

Here is the site: [www.test.joshmu.com](http://www.test.joshmu.com)

Obviously you would have to view this on an ios device to see the screen 'jitter' I am talking about.  Any help would be super appreciated!

-Update: some JS code I used for the body which works fine on normal browsers

```
//set up the page
var W = window.innerWidth;
var H = window.innerHeight;
var bodyStyle = document.body.style;
bodyStyle.backgroundColor = 'rgba(2,34,63,1)';
bodyStyle.width = W;
bodyStyle.height = H;
bodyStyle.position = 'relative';
bodyStyle.top = '0px';
bodyStyle.left = '0px';
bodyStyle.margin = '0px';
bodyStyle.padding = '0px';
bodyStyle.overflow = "hidden";
```

I should also add that when I console.log the window.onresize event, it turns out that it is constantly firing when viewing from an ios platform.

Comment: yeh i know, just not sure as to what code to provide.  Seems as though it has something to do with overflow: hidden not working on mobile devices as I have applied it to the body of the page which I appended the particles to... I'll add a part of my js script which I having been doing the particle work on.